# getText from textfields is returning null

Tags: java, swing, null, jtextfield

When the program tries to get the text from the textfields (in actionPreformed()) I get the error `java.lang.NullPointerException` even if there is text in the textfield's.

The error only occurs when the "enter" button is pushed.  All I need is to get integer values from the user using textfields when the enter button is pushed.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JTextField textField1, textField2, time;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Clock");
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
        JPanel p4 = new JPanel();

        JTextField textField1 = new JTextField(10);

        JTextField textField2 = new JTextField(10);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter the Time");

        p.add(label);

        p.add(textField1);

        p.add(textField2);

        JButton button = new JButton("Enter");

        button.addActionListener(new Main());

        p2.add(button);

        JTextField time = new JTextField();
        time.setEditable(false);

        p3.add(time);

        frame.add(p, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(p2, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.add(p3, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Enter")){

            int int1 = Integer.parseInt(textField1.getText());
            int int2 = Integer.parseInt(textField2.getText());

            System.out.println(int1);
            System.out.println(int2);
        }

        System.out.println("Pressed");
    }

}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The action performed I believe should be in the addactionlistener of the button. This acts as something called an anonymous class that has its own set of functions. The textfields although must be set as final to be used within the function of the anonymous class.

```
final JTextField textField1 = new JTextField(10);

final JTextField textField2 = new JTextField(10);

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Enter")){

            int int1 = Integer.parseInt(textField1.getText());
            int int2 = Integer.parseInt(textField2.getText());

            System.out.println(int1);
            System.out.println(int2);
        }

      System.out.println("Pressed");


    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

These lines hide the class fields of the same name, and these are used in the listener - but they aren't the ones that are added to the widget hierarchy. Hence the NPE.

```
JTextField textField1 = new JTextField(10);
JTextField textField2 = new JTextField(10);
```

Now you can't refer to the class fields in the static method main. It is always a bad idea to use main for any app specific work. Remove the code from main, put it into a true Main method, let's call it build(). Create one (!) object in main, call build() from there, remove the class names from the above two lines and set the listener using `this`- don't create another Main object!